# How to send back result and close socket in python

Tags: python, json, sockets, tensorflow, mql4

I am new in python and try to bring together a project whick get data from MT4, calculate prediction via tensorflow and send back the result. If you wannt I can attach the link of the socket server files to run the metatrader side.Sending data from MT4 is ok, the information is there.
Basic calculation in tensorflow is ok.
The problem is , I dont know how to send back data and close socket.
Thank you.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals


import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd

import socket
import ast
import json


mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8, 6)
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False

TRAIN_SPLIT = 500
tf.random.set_seed(13)

def univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size):
  data = []
  labels = []

  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i)
    # Reshape data from (history_size,) to (history_size, 1)
    data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
    labels.append(dataset[i+target_size])
  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

def train_test_model(msg=''):
    msg = msg.replace('true', 'True')
    msg = ast.literal_eval(msg)

    print(type(msg))

    if (type(msg) == dict):
        input_data = msg
    else:
        return "BAD JSON!!"

    uni_data = pd.DataFrame(input_data['Data'])# make pandas dataframe
    uni_data.index = input_data['Time']
    uni_data = uni_data.astype('float64')# convert string to float

    uni_data = uni_data.values

    uni_train_mean = uni_data[:TRAIN_SPLIT].mean()
    uni_train_std = uni_data[:TRAIN_SPLIT].std()

    uni_data = (uni_data - uni_train_mean) / uni_train_std

    univariate_past_history = 20 #int(input_data['TestingPart'] / 100 * len(data)) #
    univariate_future_target = 0 #len(data) - testSize

    x_train_uni, y_train_uni = univariate_data(uni_data, 0, TRAIN_SPLIT,
                                           univariate_past_history,
                                           univariate_future_target)


    responseJSON = {}
    responseJSON['Pred'] = str(y_train_uni[0])

    return json.dumps(responseJSON)

class socketserver:
    def __init__(self, address='', port=9090):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.address = address
        self.port = port
        self.sock.bind((self.address, self.port))
        self.cummdata = ''

    def recvmsg(self):
        self.sock.listen(1)
        self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
        print('connected to', self.addr)
        self.cummdata = ''

        while True:
            data = self.conn.recv(10000000)
            self.cummdata += data.decode("utf-8")

            if not data:
                break
           self.conn.send(bytes(train_test_model(self.cummdata), "utf-8"))

            return self.cummdata

    def __del__(self):
        self.sock.close()


serv = socketserver('127.0.0.1', 9090)

print('Socket Created at {}. Waiting for client..'.format(serv.sock.getsockname()))

while True:
   msg = serv.recvmsg()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it running fine or does `serv.recvmsg()` produce a runtime error? I see a few indentation errors in `recvmsg`. Did you intend it to look like this?

```py
    def recvmsg(self):
        self.sock.listen(1)
        self.conn, self.addr = self.sock.accept()
        print('connected to', self.addr)
        self.cummdata = ''

        while True:
            data = self.conn.recv(10000000)
            self.cummdata += data.decode("utf-8")

            if not data:
                break

        self.conn.send(bytes(train_test_model(self.cummdata), "utf-8"))

        return self.cummdata
```

Comment: the code is not mine, it is from github. I dont get any error message, the is running, but the metetrader dont get back eny result.